# Weblogic 12c - Deploy an ear twice

Tags: java, jpa, weblogic, eclipselink, java-ee-7

I'm trying to deploy an ear file twice on **Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0**. The applications are the same expect for context-root.

They have:

1. Same JPA models
2. Same persistance.xml (with same persistence-unit-name)
3. When I deploy "the second" ear and try to access to DB from the first one I receive a

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myApplication.models.entityOne
>   cannot be cast to com.myApplication.models.entityOne

It seems that the first ear uses its own models but the EntityManager of second one ear.

Structure of my ear file is something like that:

```
/
  - lib
    - jar-with-my-models.jar
    - jar-with-persistance.jar
```

Persistence.xml is defined as following:

```
 <persistence-unit name="my-persistance-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
      <jar-file>jar-with-my-models.jar</jar-file>
 </persistence-unit>
```

Weblogic.xml is defined as follows:

```
<weblogic-web-app
    xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90">
    <context-root>/console</context-root>
    <container-descriptor>
        <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>
    </container-descriptor>

    <session-descriptor>
        <persistent-store-type>memory</persistent-store-type>
        <sharing-enabled>true</sharing-enabled>
    </session-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

I'm deploying twice my ear file because I want to replicate an issue that I received during parallel deploy in WebLogic

**EDIT 1**

I noticed that entity manager inject by @PersistenceContext is the same between applications

Request on first application  *em: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy523*

Request on second application *em: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy523*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably there is a problem between Weblogic class loader if you deploy two applications on the same Weblogic Managed Server (if they share same beans - same package+class name).

I suggest you to create differents Weblogic Managed Servers for differents applications.
In this way you won't have problem.